# Falta traduzir "Code-of-conduct"

Tags: bug, tradução, internacionalização

A página ["code-of-conduct"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/code-of-conduct) (código de conduta?) está toda em inglês. Se ela já esteve em português antes (não reparei), talvez em decorrência [dessa mudança](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240594/177950) ela tenha revertido pro inglês de novo.

Comment: Falta é traduzir quase tudo na central de ajuda...

Comment: A mudança recente no nosso CoC deixou a página toda em Inglês de novo. Todo esse processo enche a paciência.